# Sonarqube not reporting results back to Jenkins and Gerrit

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, gerrit, gerrit-trigger, sonar-gerrit

Context:
Right now I have a Jenkins freestyle job that is triggered by some Gerrit events. When it is triggered, it downloads the changes and runs a Sonarqube Analysis on them. After the analysis is done, it is supposed to post comments on Gerrit detailing the results.

Unfortunately, no matter what the result of the Sonarqube analysis, the comment always says "sonarqube violations have not been found."

Some pictures:
[image]

Jenkins Freestyle Job Configuration:
[image]

[image: Post-Build configuration]

Versions:

Jenkins v2.46.2

Gerrit Trigger Plugin v.2.24.0

Sonar Gerrit Plugin v2.0

Sonarqube Scanner for Jenkins Plugin v2.6.1

Sonarqube v6.3.1

Gerrit v2.13.5

Output from the Jenkins console:

```
Unpacking https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonarsource/scanner/cli/sonar-scanner-cli/3.0.3.778/sonar-scanner-cli-3.0.3.778.zip to /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/sonar on ubuntu-graphical
[osstp-ci] $ /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/sonar/bin/sonar-scanner -e -Dsonar.host.url=<ip_address>:9000 -Dsonar.projectName=osstp-work -Dsonar.issuesReport.json.enable=true -Dsonar.report.export.path=sonar-report.json -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.projectKey=org.vmware:osstpmgt -Dsonar.inclusions=**/*.py -Dsonar.host.url=http://10.20.96.87:9000 -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/var/jenkins/workspace/osstp-ci
INFO: Option -e/--errors is no longer supported and will be ignored
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /var/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/sonar/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.0.3.778
INFO: Java 1.8.0_131 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 4.8.0-36-generic amd64
INFO: User cache: /home/tgong/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=160ms
INFO: User cache: /home/tgong/.sonar/cache
INFO: Exclude plugins: devcockpit, ldap, authgithub, authbitbucket, pdfreport, authaad, googleanalytics, governance
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=10ms
INFO: Download sonar-csharp-plugin-5.7.0.612.jar
INFO: Download sonar-python-plugin-1.7.0.1195.jar
INFO: Download sonar-java-plugin-4.5.0.8398.jar
INFO: Download sonar-flex-plugin-2.3.jar
INFO: Download sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.2.jar
INFO: Download sonar-php-plugin-2.9.2.1744.jar
INFO: Download sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.4.0.522.jar
INFO: Download sonar-javascript-plugin-2.20.0.4207.jar
INFO: SonarQube server 6.3.1
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=217ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=66ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=1693ms
INFO: Load metrics repository
INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=141ms
INFO: Issues mode
INFO: Scanning only changed files
INFO: Project key: org.vmware:osstpmgt
INFO: -------------  Scan osstp-work
INFO: Load server rules
INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=68ms
INFO: Base dir: /var/jenkins/workspace/osstp-ci
INFO: Working dir: /var/jenkins/workspace/osstp-ci/.scannerwork
INFO: Source paths: .
INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
INFO: Index files
INFO: Included sources: 
INFO:   **/*.py
WARN: Not indexing due to symlink loop: /var/jenkins/workspace/osstp-ci/www/scotzilla
INFO: 717 files indexed
INFO: 2093 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
INFO: Quality profile for py: Sonar way
INFO: Sensor NoSonar Sensor [php]
INFO: Sensor NoSonar Sensor [php] (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor Coverage Report Import [csharp]
INFO: Sensor Coverage Report Import [csharp] (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor Coverage Report Import [csharp]
INFO: Sensor Coverage Report Import [csharp] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor Unit Test Results Import [csharp]
INFO: Sensor Unit Test Results Import [csharp] (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor XmlFileSensor [java]
INFO: Sensor XmlFileSensor [java] (done) | time=7ms
INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php]
INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php] (done) | time=8ms
INFO: Load server issues
INFO: Load server issues (done) | time=1053ms
INFO: Performing issue tracking
INFO: 813/813 components tracked
INFO: Export issues to /var/jenkins/workspace/osstp-ci/.scannerwork/sonar-report.json
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL
INFO: Task total time: 11.610 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 17.577s
INFO: Final Memory: 46M/114M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Getting Sonar Report from: /var/jenkins/workspace/osstp-ci/.scannerwork/sonar-report.json
Report has loaded and contains 1492 issues
Connected to Gerrit: server name: Gerrit. Change Number: 32, PatchSetNumber: 1
Review has been sent
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Based on the first picture some analysis has been done or are these results from the past? Did you have a look in the SonarQube log files for some exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you already resolved this, but your "Project Settings" entry is empty and there was a recent fix (Jan 2018 - JENKINS-43730) that addresses what may have caused your issue: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Sonar+Gerrit#SonarGerrit-Version2.1(6Jan2018)

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the following:

1) Build > Execute SonarQube Scanner > Analysis properties

```
sonar.report.export.path=sonar-report.json
```

2) Post-build Actions > Post SonarQube issues as Gerrit comments > Project Settings

```
SonarQube report path = .sonar/sonar-report.json
```

Comment: I did that, except I set `SonarQube report path = .scannerwork/sonar-report.json`.

Comment: The console output says `Report has loaded and contains 2425 issues` but Gerrit still says `No Sonarqube violations have been found.`

Comment: Why .scannerwork/ instead of /.sonar? Was the .json report generated there? Did you check?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't specify. Now I can find the report in .scannerwork/sonar-report.json, so the post-build action can find the report now.
The Jenkins job still posts comments to Gerrit that say "No Sonarqube violations have been found."

Comment: Please add more info from Jenkins console.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `user.dir` property is not set. Set it to the location where git downloads the code (most probably in `$WORKSPACE`)
so, include this `user.dir=$WORKSPACE` with the other analysis parameters.